# Next.js 12 + Supabase project error "No storage option exists to persist the session"

Tags: next.js, supabase-js

I am working on a project using Supabase and Next.js 12.3.4, and I have set up Google sign in using this tutorial: [Supabase Login with Google](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-google). When I run the project, Terminal repeatedly warns

```
No storage option exists to persist the session, which may result in unexpected behavior when using auth.
        If you want to set persistSession to true, please provide a storage option or you may set persistSession to false to disable this warning.
```

This is the code to sign in:

```
import supabaseClient from "./supabaseClient";

export default async function signInWithGoogle() {
    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithOAuth({
        provider: 'google',
        options: {
            redirectTo: 'http://localhost:3000/account'
        }
    })
}
```

One response to someone else's [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/14dgv73/supabase_no_storage_option_exists_to_persist_the/) about this suggested following [this tutorial](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs-pages), which I tried as my project also has a pages directory. However, the tutorial refers to a src/App.jsx file with an App function, whereas I have a pages/_app.js file with "export default class MyApp extends App", for which the tutorial doesn't work--Attempting to use the recommended code in _app.js resulted in `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

This is my **_app.js** file:

```
import App from 'next/app'
import Head from 'next/head'
import React from 'react'
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';
import font from "/components/styles.css";


export default class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
        let pageProps = {}

        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        }

        return { pageProps }
    }

    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

        return (
            <>
                <Head>
                    <title>words</title>
                   
                </Head>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                <Analytics />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I resolve the storage error? (I am new to all of these technologies, so this may have an obvious solution.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your responses. What I ended up doing (which unfortunately doesn't answer this question with the parameters I originally stated) was upgrading the project to Nextjs 13 (as this made another aspect of the project much easier to carry out). After upgrading, I set up Supabase according to this tutorial: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs and altered the signInWithGoogle function:

```
import { createClientComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"

export default async function signInWithGoogle() {
    const supabase = createClientComponentClient()
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
        provider: 'google',
        options: {
            redirectTo: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/callback'
        }
    })
}
```

The error stopped after the project was upgraded.

Answer (score 6):

I was also facing this issue when i used supabase in node ,Hope it might fix your  issue

```js
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, {
  auth: { persistSession: false },
});
```

Comment: I am using Supabase in a backend service (with service key) without user auth, this is the best option for me

Answer (score 4):

If you use Redux for state management and want to integrate it with Supabase, you can use redux-persist with redux-persist/lib/storage as the storage mechanism. The warning should go away.

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
const supabase = createClient( supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, {auth: {storage: storage}});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had my superbase `createClient` in a different file and I was importing that on the client. Turns out that makes the code run on the server as well during SSR.

To fix it, all I did was remove that extra file and put the `createClient` call inside an empty useEffect. This fixed it.

Ex:

```
const [supabase, setSupabase] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setSupabase(createClient(config.SUPABASE_URL, config.SUPABASE_KEY));
  }, []);
```

Hope this helps!